# Find index of array with specific length in a List?

Tags: c#, list, linq, indexing

In my application, I have a `List<float[]>` with arrays varying in sizes each time the application runs. I want to find out the index of arrays in that `List<float[]>` with length less than or equal to a specified value.

Lets say I have a List `[ float[100], float[80], float[101] ]`. Now I want to know the indexes of those arrays whose length is less than or equal to **100**.

I can create Loop and Iterate through each element in the list but that way seems too long. Is there any LINQ way possible?

Comment: You would not need to iterate through each array, you could use the Length property.

Comment: You can get indices using Linq, but it requires a lookup table iirc.  A simple for loop seems like a fine way to go.

Comment: @hijinxbassist I was saying the same thing that I can go through each element in the List and use the length property to filter out the arrays that are satisfying the length condition.

Comment: but I really don't get why my question gets a downvote.

Comment: @hijinxbassist: What *exactly* do you mean by "a lookup table" here? A natural LINQ query would just iterate over the list.

Comment: @JonSkeet I was questioning my wording there last night.  Lookup table definitely was not the right choice of words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Linq's `Select` to get the indexes, and `Where` to filter them out:

```cs
List<int> indexes = list.Select((arr, ind) => (arr, ind))
                        .Where(x => x.arr.Length <= 100)
                        .Select(x => x.ind)
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: OP wants to kwow indexes of filtered items, if I'm not wrong. Maybe he asked the wrong question, I don't know...

Comment: @Marco I completely misread the question somehow... Edited and fixed.

Comment: @Marco Yes exactly, I wanted to know the index of those arrays that are satisfying the length constraint.

Comment: @Mureinik thank you for reply, but I am unable to compile the code as it is showing an error on the first Select statement which says, "A local variable named 'arr' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'arr', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else"

Comment: Ok.. I get it, @Mureinik I guess you mistakenly wrote `find` instead of `ind` in your first `Select` statement. after this quick fix I'm able to compile this code in LINQPad 6 but its still giving error in Visual Studio. https://imgur.com/yvYL4BM

Comment: @abhinavp650: That looks like the kind of error you'd get if you're targeting an old version of .NET. The code itself is fine - it just needs ValueTuple support. You could change `(arr, ind) => (arr, ind)` to `(arr, ind) => new { arr, ind }` and it should compile (but will be less efficient).

Comment: @JonSkeet wow.. making that change really did the job and you exactly pointed out the reason behind the error. My application is based on `4.6.2` while LINQPad 6 is compiling it under `.NET 5.0`. I found that ValueTuple support is there in versions above `4.6.2`. Can you please explain a little how is it more advantageous over `new {arr, ind }`?

Comment: @abhinavp650: `new { arr, ind }` uses an anonymous type, which is a class - so it's creating a new object for each element in the array. `(arr, ind)` is a `ValueTuple`, which is a value type - no new objects being created. The new objects for the anonymous type version will be short-lived, so the performance difference may very well not be significant... it's just worth being aware of the difference.

Comment: @JonSkeet that made everything clear.. thanks a lot.